# Prove that there is only one $y=h(x)$ so that $y+x^2y^3+x+y^5x^4=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Prove that $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ there is only one $y=h(x)$ so that 
$$y+x^2y^3+x+y^5x^4=1$$

I am currenty studying multi-variable calculus on my own and I have no clue how to solve this problem. Which results of multi-variable calculus do I have to study to solve it? I would appreciate if someone could solve it or share similiar problems to this one.

Comment: @dxiv sorry, I meant $\mathbb{R}$. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

$\,x = 0 \implies y=1\,$ i.e. $\,h(0)=1\,$. For $\,x \ne 0\,$, let $\,z=xy\,$, then multiply by $\,x\,$, and write it as:

$$
z^5+z^3+z = x - x^2
$$

The LHS $\,f(z)=z^5+z^3+z\,$ is continuous and strictly increasing on $\,\mathbb{R}\,$, and since the limits at $\,\pm \infty\,$ are $\,\pm\infty\,$ respectively, it follows that $\,f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\,$ is a bijection. Then the unique solution of the equation is $\displaystyle\,z = f^{-1}(x-x^2) \iff y = \frac{f^{-1}(x-x^2)}{x} = h(x)\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   Following up on the comments, such problems would be solved in the general case using the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem). Here in particular $\,f(x,y) = y^5x^4+y^3x^2+y+x-1\,$, and $\displaystyle\,\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}(x,y)=5y^4x^4+3y^2x^2+1 \ge 1\,$ is never $\,0\,$, so the map $\,y=h(x)\,$ is defined at all points.

Comment: Wow. This is an amazing answer, but I suspect like the OP I would never have come to an answer like this. If you have time, can you give some insight about what you noticed apriori that allowed you to devise this solution?

Comment: Yes please, what should I be looking for when solving this problems?

Comment: @codingnight In the general case, you would look at the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem). I'll add a note to the answer about that. However, given the particular form of the equation here, my guess is that it was meant to be solved using a shortcut such as the one above, rather than the full weight of the implicit function theorem. The clue for me was that all terms in $\,y\,$ contained a power of $\,x\,$ exactly one less.

Comment: @IntegrateThis See my previous comment, and the edit added at the end.